# How can I effectively "sentry jump" with the wrangler?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-engineer

Now that the wrangler has been introduced to the engineer, the engineer can get to places previously unreachable.  Is it possible to get propelled upward with just the gun from the sentry to take less damage? If rockets are used, is it possible to pick up the sentry immediately after rocket launch, so that you can take the sentry with you on the jump? What other tips do you have?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can reduce damage and fly farther by jumping and crouching in mid-air as you shoot the rocket.

To answer your other question, I present you [a page of helpful videos](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Sentry_jump) instead.

Answer (score 4):

I'm honestly not sure about using the gun to propel, or if you can microsecond-time the pickup of the sentry post rocketblast. However, the fairly obvious tip would be to build a teleporter exit in a safe spot wherever you rocket jump to and have your entrance waiting in a convenient spot for afterwards. You'll be able to move your sentry / dispenser quickly without the hassle of having to rebuild everything.

Answer (score 1):

You can also propel yourself using shots from the mini-sentry.  Stand on top of the mini-sentry and shoot upwards.

Answer (score 1):

I was practicing sentry jumps the other day and came to discover that if you:

1. Stand on top the sentry
2. Look down at it
3. Simultaniously **right click** (rocket) and **press <kbd>3</kbd>** (change to wrench)

You can pickup the sentry whilst jumping relatively easily to carry it to new places.

you may have to right click just before you press <kbd>3</kbd> and spamming right click instead of just hitting it once can also help

Hope this helps :D

Comment: With the inclusion of the Rescue Ranger you don't need to worry about switching to wrench and trying to pick up your sentry at the same time, you can just jump over and 'Ranger the sentry to you.  That is, if you have that item, for those of us who don't you have a good method though :)

Comment: @hammythepig Yes, however, this method is useful when either you dont have it (as you've mentioned), or when you dont wish to spend metal to activate the Rescue Ranger, or even if you just prefer a different wrench :)